"I want someone to do something." — Where are arguments here?
In an ongoing attempt to find the examples where complements and arguments don't coincide with each other, I came across these two answers of the user "BillJ".
from BillJ's answer on english.stackexchange.com:

(1) I want him to call me tomorrow.
"Him" is not an argument of "want". What I want is not "him", but "him to call me tomorrow".

from BillJ's answer on ell.stackexchange.com:

(2) I want you to go there.
"I" is not an argument of "want", thus "want" has three complements ("I", “you” and "to go there", but only two arguments "you" and "to go there").

I have some questions:
Why is "I" in (2) not an argument? I thought subjects are always arguments.
Why is "him" in (1) not an argument of "want" whereas "you" in (2) is an argument of "want"?
How to understand where the arguments are in these sentences?

I don't see any reason why these should not be analyzed similarly. They're all instances of the "X want Y to Z" pattern.

So it looks like @BillJ made a mistake in one of them.

To be consistent with (1), in (2) the argument should be "you to go there".
